# Include rails precompiled asset pipeline .JS with md5 hash in filename in static page? or exclude it from getting a hash in the filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, precompile

Rails 3.2 asset precompiling appends the filename with a hash. I would like to use some of my assets outside of rails ( for a maintenance page ) I would like to include some .JS files from the precompiled asset folder.

Is there a way exclude certain files from the md5 hash that's appending to the filename? 
Or otherwise make them available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find something like this in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all
# non-JS/CSS are already added)
# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

You should add any assets you want to be able to link to individually, or additional manifest files, to the `config.assets.precompile` array.

For example, you could make a `maintenance.js` manifest file containing:

```
//= require foo
//= require bar
```

Add it to `config.assets.precompile`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( maintenance.js )
```

And then on your maintenance page:

```
<%= javascript_link_tag 'maintenance' %>
```

See the [precompiling assets section in the asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) for more information.